# Getting items from a SharePoint Online list with React "Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a web part which I use in SharePoint Online and it is giving me an error.
It renders a list of items with paging at the bottom.

I currently get the error below

```
  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')
```

which is pointing to my "componentDidMount"

console.log output is ...

2 PagedLinks setState:
2 PagedLinks items:
2 PagedLinks items length:0
2 PagedLinks setState done:
1 PagedLinks items:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
1 PagedLinks items length:23

Any ideas?

Thanks
P

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './PagedLinks.module.scss';
import { IPagedLinksProps } from './IPagedLinksProps';
import { IPagedLinksState } from './IPagedLinksState';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { ISPItem } from '../models/ISPItem';
import { Pagination } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/pagination";
import pnp from "sp-pnp-js";

const pageSize: number = 5;

export default class PnPPagination extends React.Component<IPagedLinksProps, IPagedLinksState> {
  constructor(props: IPagedLinksProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      allItems: [],
      paginatedItems: []
    };
  }

  // public componentDidMount(): void {
  //   const items: ISPItem[] = this.getSPListItems();
  //   this.setState({ allItems: items, paginatedItems: items.slice(0, pageSize) });
  // }

  public async componentDidMount(): Promise<void> {
     //const items: ISPItem[] = this.getSPListItems();
     const items: ISPItem[] = [];
     //var reacthandler = this;

     pnp.sp.web.lists
     //.getByTitle("theURLs")
     .getByTitle("theURLs")
     .items.select("Title","URL")
     .get()
     .then(function (data) {
       for (var k in data) {
         items.push({ title: data[k].Title, description: data[k].URL });
       }
       //reacthandler.setState({ items });
       console.log('1 PagedLinks items:' + items);
       console.log('1 PagedLinks items length:' + items.length);
     
       this.setState({ allItems: items, paginatedItems: items.slice(0, pageSize) });

       

       //return items;
     });


     console.log('2 PagedLinks setState:');
     console.log('2 PagedLinks items:' + items);
     console.log('2 PagedLinks items length:' + items.length);
     this.setState({ allItems: items, paginatedItems: items.slice(0, pageSize) });
     console.log('2 PagedLinks setState done:');
  }


  public render(): React.ReactElement<IPagedLinksProps> {
    return (
      <div className={styles.pagedLinks}>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            {
              this.state.paginatedItems.map((item) =>
                <div>{item.title}</div>
              )
            }
            <Pagination
              currentPage={1}
              totalPages={(this.state.allItems.length / pageSize) - 1}
              onChange={(page) => this._getPage(page)}
              limiter={3}
              
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  private _getPage(page: number) {
    // round a number up to the next largest integer.
    const roundupPage = Math.ceil(page);

    this.setState({
      paginatedItems: this.state.allItems.slice(roundupPage * pageSize, (roundupPage * pageSize) + pageSize)
    });
  }

  public getSPListItems(): ISPItem[] {
    // const spItems: ISPItem[] = [
    //   { title: "stove", description: "completely" },
    //   { title: "rich", description: "know" },
    //   { title: "composed", description: "explain" },
    //   { title: "said", description: "simply" },
    //   { title: "sum", description: "bear" },
    //   { title: "bowl", description: "exclaimed" },
    //   { title: "help", description: "drive" },
    
    // ];

    const spItems: ISPItem[] = [
         { title: "stove", description: "completely" }
    ];

    pnp.sp.web.lists
    //.getByTitle("theURLs")
    .getByTitle("theURLs")
    .items.select("Title","URL")
    .get()
    .then(function (data) {
      for (var k in data) {
        spItems.push({ title: data[k].Title, description: data[k].URL });
      }
      //reacthandler.setState({ items });
      //console.log(items);
      return spItems;
    });

    return spItems;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You using "then" method You lose "this" context. There few ways around it. I think the easiest is to use await keyword to handle async calls

```
    public async componentDidMount(): Promise<void> {
    //const items: ISPItem[] = this.getSPListItems();
    const items: ISPItem[] = [];
    //var reacthandler = this;

    const data = await pnp.sp.web.lists
    //.getByTitle("theURLs")
    .getByTitle("theURLs")
    .items.select("Title","URL")
    .get()
    for (var k in data) {
        items.push({ title: data[k].Title, description: data[k].URL });
      }
      //reacthandler.setState({ items });
      console.log('1 PagedLinks items:' + items);
      console.log('1 PagedLinks items length:' + items.length);
    
      this.setState({ allItems: items, paginatedItems: items.slice(0, pageSize) });
 }
```

Hope that will help.